# JupyterLab editor ignores indent setting an notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, indentation, jupyter-lab

When using JupyterLab, the indent setting seems to be ignored on notebook files (.ipynb). Tested with jupyterlab 3.1.1 (installed from pypi).

My user settings of the JupyterLab editor contains the following setting:

```
{
    "editorConfig": {
        "cursorBlinkRate": 530,
        "fontFamily": null,
        "fontSize": null,
        "lineHeight": null,
        "lineNumbers": true,
        "lineWrap": "on",
        "wordWrapColumn": 80,
        "readOnly": false,
        "tabSize": 4,
        "insertSpaces": false,
        "matchBrackets": true,
        "autoClosingBrackets": false,
        "rulers": [],
        "codeFolding": false
    }
}
```

I would expect, that the editor inserts a tab character when indenting with the tab-key, but it still inserts 4 spaces.

Jupyther notebook is able to insert tabs. I have the following settings in `~/.jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json`:

```
{
  "CodeCell": {
    "cm_config": {
      "indentWithTabs": true
    }
  }
}
```

With this setting, the normal notebook-editor is inserting tabs instead of spaces.

Is it possible, to have JupyterLab using tabs for indent characters on notebooks as well?

Comment: It is the Python standard (in PEP 8) to use spaces, not tabs. There are good reasons for this.

Comment: This looks like a valid feature request (could be useful for other languages). Have you searched for existing issues on JupyterLab GitHub repository?

Comment: Here is the link: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/10751 - I was wrong, it seems that everything is fine and there is no need to request a feature ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This editor setting is not affecting notebooks (at least not yet).

To get indentation with tabs (or other number of spaces than 4) in notebooks, you need to go to "Settings"->"Advanced Settings Editor". In the left pane select "Notebook" and insert the following in the user settings pane:

```
{
    "codeCellConfig": {
        "insertSpaces": false
    },
    "markdownCellConfig": {
        "insertSpaces": false,
    },
    "rawCellConfig": {
        "insertSpaces": false,
    }
}
```

See https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/10751#issuecomment-890181712